# how can an objects points on many other objects in JAVA?

Tags: java, pointers, tree, trie

I'm trying to build a TRIE, but for that I need that the root of the tree would be able to point on sons as much as I want to create (since it's supposed to use as Prefix tree).

So I'd like to know if it is even possible make many pointers that are going out of my root objects to all of my tire's sons?
And I'd like to see how exactly.

Comment: You mean like a list of pointers?

Comment: Have you considered using a List<Object> to store the child nodes ? that way a root can have any number of child nodes. Also, there is no such thing as pointers in java - you only have references. And you can store each reference in the List<Object>.

Comment: yeah well i know i just call them like that...

Comment: anyway can you show me how to make pointers and save them in a list?   im not sure if i write : root = leftNode and then root = RightNode...i will lose the first "pointer" no?

Comment: http://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a trie, you'll want a way to turn a letter into a reference to the next node. There are 2 obvious choices:

- a array `Node[] nodes = new Node[26];` (assuming English language)
- a `Map<Character, Node> map = new HashMap<Character, Node>();`

The array is the classic C approach, but since you're working in java I would start off with the map because it's easier to work with.

Comment: Just curious as to what would be the purpose of the `Node` value in the HashMap?

Comment: I am surprised that such a comment is coming from a moderator. It may be obvious for you but it's not obvious for me. Would you like to explain why you need a Node class when you can just use a nested Map?

Comment: @ChetanKinger tries need a node to store information about the location - specifically if it's a word or not. You *could* shoehorn a special value into a map for this value, so the map becomes the node, but that is unnecessary (and I've never heard of it being done). The reason I responded like it did is that to explain why would be to explain what a trie is - too long for this format.

Comment: @Bohmian. Fair enough. Although, I still feel that your answer should be explaining the structure of the `Node` class specially because it is stored as a value in the `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not use the term `pointers`. It uses the term `references`. While references exhibit some of the behavior of pointers such as `pass-by-value` when passed to a method, they are still called `references`.

Moving on to the actual question. You can use a `Collection` of references. Consider the following example :

```
class Node {
     List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

     public void addNode(Node d) {
         children.add(d);
     }   

     /*Get Nth child */
     public Node getChild(int n) {
         if(n<children.size()) 
            return children.get(n);

         return null;
     }
 }
```

You can also use a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList` depending on what you wish to achieve. A `LinkedList` will give fast insertion and deletion whereas an `ArrayList` will give you fast iteration.

Comment: thank u. so when i want to use my references what would be the "get" method?

Comment: @noylevi Edited the answer to demonstrate one possible way to get the child nodes (get the Nth child node). Don't forget to click on the tick and accept the answer if this answer was what you were looking for :)